# Ordem de execução do código com window.alert

Tags: javascript

Fiz um jogo de perguntas e respostas, ao acertar o jogador ganha um ponto, ao errar perde um ponto, ao fazer dez pontos o jogador vence. A cada resposta certa fica verde, aparece escrito acertou e é exibido o número de acertos. Porém no décimo acerto o alert dizendo que o jogador venceu é executado antes do código dizendo que ele acertou.Esse é o código,se alguém puder me explicar, obrigado!
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<script>
    var respostaCerta
    var a=window.document.getElementById('a')
    var b=window.document.getElementById('b')
    var acertos=0
    var erros=0
    var resposta=window.document.getElementById('resposta')
    var verif=window.document.getElementById('verificar')
    resposta.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
            if (event.keyCode == 13){
                verificar()
            } 
            //alert(event.keyCode);
        });
    function iniciar(){
        setFocoResposta()
        sortear() 
        acertos=0
        erros=0
        exibirEstrelas()
        exibirErrosAcertos()
    }
    function setFocoResposta(){
        window.document.getElementById('resposta').focus()
    }
    function sortear(){ 
        a.innerHTML=String(Number.parseInt(Math.random()*6))
        b.innerHTML=String(Number.parseInt(Math.random()*6))
        respostaCerta=Number.parseInt(a.innerText)+Number.parseInt(b.innerText)
        //window.alert('testado sortear')
    }
    function verificar(){ 
        var res=window.document.getElementById('res')
        if(resposta.value==''){
            res.innerHTML='CAMPO EM BRANCO, DIGITE UM VALOR!'
            setFocoResposta()
            window.setTimeout(campoVazio,4000)
        }else
        if(Number.isInteger(Number(resposta.value))!=true){
            res.innerHTML='DIGITE APENAS NÚMEROS INTEIROS!'
            resposta.value=''
            setFocoResposta()
            window.setTimeout(campoVazio,4000)
        }else
        if(Number.parseInt(resposta.value)==Number.parseInt(respostaCerta)){
            verif.setAttribute('disabled', true)
            resposta.setAttribute('disabled',true)
            res.innerHTML='ACERTOU!'
            res.style.background='green'
            acerto()
            window.setTimeout(limpar,2000)
            if(acertos==10){
                window.alert(`PARABÉNS! VOCÊ VENCEU! NOTA: ${Number.parseInt((acertos*10)/(erros+acertos))}`)
                iniciar()
            }
            
        }else
        if(Number.parseInt(resposta.value)!=Number.parseInt(respostaCerta)){
            verif.setAttribute('disabled', true)
            resposta.setAttribute('disabled',true)
            res.innerHTML=`ERROU! ${a.innerHTML} + ${b.innerHTML} = ${respostaCerta}`
            res.style.background='red'
            erro()
            window.setTimeout(limpar,4000)
        }            
    }
    function acerto(){
        acertos+=1
        exibirEstrelas()
        exibirErrosAcertos()
    }
    function erro(){
        erros+=1
        acertos-=1
        if(acertos<0){
            acertos=0
        }
        exibirEstrelas()
        exibirErrosAcertos()
    }
    function exibirEstrelas(){
        var estrelas=window.document.getElementById('head')
        if(acertos==0){
            estrelas.innerHTML='<h1>WILSON MATH</h1>'
        }else
        if(acertos==1){
            estrelas.innerHTML='<h1> * </h1>'
        }else
        if(acertos==2){
            estrelas.innerHTML='<h1> * * </h1>'
        }else
        if(acertos==3){
            estrelas.innerHTML='<h1> * * * </h1>'
        }else
        if(acertos==4){
            estrelas.innerHTML='<h1> * * * * </h1>'
        }else
        if(acertos==5){
            estrelas.innerHTML='<h1> * * * * * </h1>'
        }else
        if(acertos==6){
            estrelas.innerHTML='<h1> * * * * * * </h1>'
        }else
        if(acertos==7){
            estrelas.innerHTML='<h1> * * * * * * * </h1>'
        }else
        if(acertos==8){
            estrelas.innerHTML='<h1> * * * * * * * * </h1>'
        }else
        if(acertos==9){
            estrelas.innerHTML='<h1> * * * * * * * * * </h1>'
        }else
        if(acertos==10){
            estrelas.innerHTML='<h1> * * * * * * * * * * </h1>'
        }
        
    }
    function campoVazio(){
        res.innerHTML='RESULTADO'
    }
    function limpar(){
        res.innerHTML='RESULTADO'
        res.style.background='#3A7CAB'
        resposta.value=''
        sortear()
        verif.removeAttribute("disabled")
        resposta.removeAttribute("disabled")
        setFocoResposta()
    }
    function exibirErrosAcertos(){
        let nErros=window.document.getElementById('erros')
        let nAcertos=window.document.getElementById('acertos')
        nErros.innerHTML=`ERROS: ${erros}`
        nAcertos.innerHTML=`ACERTOS: ${acertos}`  
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Coloca um setTimeout antes do alert ou algum efeito de transição pra ele demorar mais pra aparecer. Pode postar o código completo? às vezes tem algum detalhe dentro do acerto() que possa fazer diferença nesse contexto.

Answer (score 0):

É simples, vc botou:

```js
if(acertos==10){
            window.alert(`PARABÉNS! VOCÊ VENCEU! NOTA: ${Number.parseInt((acertos*10)/(erros+acertos))}`)
            iniciar()}
```

So que ai mano tu meio que não mandou o javascript dizer que o cara acertou para só depois dizer que ele ganho se a pontuação for igual a 10, para resolver é simples, é so botar um acerto() antes do `window.alert(`PARABÉNS! VOCÊ VENCEU! NOTA:${Number.parseInt((acertos*10)/(erros+acertos))} `)`

O código fica assim:

```js
    res.innerHTML='ACERTOU!'
            res.style.background='green'
            acerto()
            window.setTimeout(limpar,2000)
            if(acertos==10){
            acertou() // a mudança que eu fiz
            window.alert(`PARABÉNS! VOCÊ VENCEU! NOTA: ${Number.parseInt((acertos*10)/(erros+acertos))}`)
            iniciar()}
```

Comment: Postei o código quase completo, é como se no décimo acerto não fosse executado o código que vem antes do alert.

Comment: Eu sei, tenta ler um pouco melhor o que eu escrevi, eu resolvi o problema ai em cima

Comment: Testei o que falou, coloquei o código também dentro do if mas também não rolou, se a condição dá verdadeira tudo que vem antes do alert não é executado. Consegui resolver o problema colocando esse if dentro da função de limpar, mas ainda não entendi por que os códigos que veem antes do if ou antes do alert não são executados quando a condição dava verdadeira..